# Virtualbox share is read-only

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mount

Here I've a strange behavior:

Virtualbox (version 5) with 6 shares to windows host system.
Four of them working fine, two of them are read-only. Configuration is similar.

/etc/fstab:

```
download    /media/sf_Download/ vboxsf defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw    0   0
p80 /media/sf_p80/  vboxsf  defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw   0   0
p40 /media/sf_p40/  vboxsf  defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw   0   0
p20 /media/sf_p20/  vboxsf  defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw   0   0
musik   /media/sf_musik/    vboxsf  defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw   0   0
filme   /media/sf_filme/    vboxsf  defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw   0   0
```

the upper four are mounted r+w, all fine. but the lower two are read-only. Tryed several things (chown, chmod, etc), but nothing helped.

In case musik and filme are not mounted, ls -l delivers:

```
user@virtualxubuntu:/media$ ls -l
insgesamt 44
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 root       vboxsf      4096 Jun 16 13:55 user
drwxrwxrwx  2 root       vboxsf      4096 Jun 16 15:42 sf_filme
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user        4096 Jun 16 15:35 sf_Download
drwxrwxrwx  2 root       vboxsf      4096 Jun 16 15:43 sf_musik
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user       20480 Mai 29 04:34 sf_p20
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user        4096 Mai 29 04:34 sf_p40
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user        4096 Mai 29 04:34 sf_p80
```

After mount -a I get:

```
user@virtualxubuntu:/media$ ls -l
insgesamt 252
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 root       vboxsf       4096 Jun 16 13:55 user
dr-xr-xr-x  1 user       user        98304 Jun 15 17:39 sf_filme
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user         4096 Jun 16 15:35 sf_Download
dr-xr-xr-x  1 user       user       122880 Mär 31 13:07 sf_musik
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user        20480 Mai 29 04:34 sf_p20
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user         4096 Mai 29 04:34 sf_p40
drwxrwxrwx  1 user       user         4096 Mai 29 04:34 sf_p80
```

Do you have any idea, how to fix it? The strange thing: this configuration worked months, 'til yesterday. And "I didn't changed anything." ;-)

kind regards
Johannes

Answer (score 1):

Strange...
I added fmode and dmode options to the failing mounts and this helped...

```
musik   /media/sf_musik/    vboxsf  defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,fmode=0644,dmode=0750   0   0
filme   /media/sf_filme/    vboxsf  defaults,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,fmode=0644,dmode=0750   0   0
```

Don't know why these two need this options...